# How are resources added to the sample jar produced in Maven's guide?

Tags: java, maven, jar, resources, meta-inf

As someone new to this, I might just be missing something obvious, but I figure it might be confusing to anyone unaware in the field of developing tools like Maven. Following the official Maven guide, I was able to install the sample JAR to the appropriate repository.

The structure of added resources seems intuitive, but the way things are written, it is unclear to me what is manual and what is automatic for the sample project of the guide. The guide starts this section as if they manually added the resources directory (with random sub-folders) in the location of the main folder of the src directory (which I guess can also be done by adding the resources element in project build), but then it talks of the contents of those random folders as if they appear automatically when you unpack the JAR that was installed previously. Yet I see no prior talk about the procedure to unpack the JAR. Clicking or trying to work with the JAR produced in "my-app" of the repository in the .m2 folder directly doesn't seem to produce anything. Are we expected to know about some command that automatically will unpack the JAR to produce the resources directory with the META-INF contents (MANIFEST.MF, application.properties, etc...)?

I couldn't find anything specific to this issue, and I don't want to risk anything to jeopardize my progress considering I have had issues just trying to reproduce my progress again with a different title yet as another of the sample project. If what I've asked here is actually mostly automatic just because this is the sample project in Maven's guide, what should I be aware of in terms of this specific issue that will require extra manual steps when trying to create a new project from scratch?

EDIT: the end goal is that I understand how I can use Maven to produce a .jar that won't get me the error "no main manifest attribute" in a launch4j build (since working with my java file and the command prompt doesn't do that).

Comment: It is not very clear what you actually want, Please have a line or two and describe what exactly u want to achieve

Comment: I don't know if the edit to the end of the question helps, but I wanted to limit the scope of the answer to just where I am stuck as I am aware that there is a lot to work with in Maven (especially since I was wondering if anything extra is required for a 2nd simple project separate from the sample in the guide). I kept the title as is because I am sure from what I've seen, knowing how to properly produce the resources directory is key to allowing me to access the MANIFEST.MF needed to stop the launch4j error. I have already seen what I need to do next once I get that far.